# Azure Data Factory Data flow expression builder using parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass pipeline parameter to Data flow activity while I try to pass the value for my directory/folder. As `concat('myArchive/', $myFolderDF)` gives me the error: `Column operands are not allowed in literal expressions`. I tried using this `'{$myFolderDF}'` and still get the error. Could you please guide me on using parameters in expressions in Data flow activity.

***JSON:***

```
parameters{
    myFolderDF as string
}
source(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    format: 'csv',
    fileSystem: 'FileSource',
    folderPath: (concat('myFileArchive/',$myFolderDF)),
    fileName: (concat(lower($myFolderDF),'.csv')),
    documentForm: 'documentPerLine') ~> DFSource
DFSource sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    format: 'csv',
    fileSystem: 'FileArchive',
    folderPath: (concat('myFileArchive/',$myFolderDF)),
    partitionFileNames:[(concat($myFolderDF,toString(currentTimestamp(),'MMddyyyy'),'.csv'))],
    umask: 0022,
    preCommands: [],
    postCommands: [],
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,
    saveOrder: 0,
    partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> DFFileArchive
```

[image: PipelineParameter]

[image: DataflowParameter]

Comment: You may need to try something like `@concat('myArchive/', '@{pipeline().parameters.myFolderDF}')`. Make sure your parameter/variables are enclosed with curly brackets `{ }` and associated with `@`

Comment: You can hardcode 'myarchive/' in the dataset itself or you can also mention under source option under wildcard path. Keep the data flow param expression simple by passing @{pipeline().parameters.myFolderDF}. From within the data flow, you can simply use this as $dataflowparamname

Comment: Hi @ray, I tried curly braces for the parameter marker and still get the same error.

Comment: Hi @AllAboutBI, I tried your method too and get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to get it correctly when I trigger pipeline run. Please check the below configuration as an example.

Assuming this is *not related to Dataset parameter* and the source dataset has no *explicit* **file path** provided.

[image]

**Dataflow configuration:**

**Dataflow Parameter:** `get_dir`

[image]

**Wildcard paths:** `concat('my/',$get_dir)`

[image]

[image]

**Pipeline Parameter:** `pipe_param`

[image]

**Assigned to DataFlow Parameter:**

```
get_dir: @pipeline().parameters.pipe_param
```

[image]

**Passing dynamic value:**

Original file location: `source / my / myArchive / mysource (1).csv`

Parameterized: `source / concat('my/',$get_dir)`

Dynamic value: `myArchive/*.csv`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @KarthikBhyresh-MT, I was doing everything the same as mentioned in your response and still get the same error. I have updated OP with json.

Comment: oki how are you getting the value passed to $myFolderDF from pipeline. Like, in my example I am manually typing it in during pipeline run prompt. Are you getting it dynamically ? from any other activity before data flow in pipeline?

Comment: Hi @KarthikBhyresh-MT, I updated my OP with images. I am passing the value via the pipeline run prompt. In the pipeline for the Data flow activity parameter this is the value I'm passing `@pipeline().parameters.myFolderDF` and within the Data flow parameters I'm leaving it blank. Its hard to debug the Data flow activity to see what values are passed into the expression during **Debug**.

Comment: When I look at the Data flow activity input json I see the parameter value passing correctly.

Comment: oki, can you uncheck the `Expression` property in dataflow parameter option from pipeline. And make sure there are no trailing spaces or in the beginning or between the parameter names or the input value.

Comment: Hi @KarthikBhyresh-MT, Works now thank you.

Comment: it's my pleasure 

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT I was having same problem and this post solved it. Thank You. But I was assuming it as an expression and checked it. Can I know when and when not to check expression check box?